# Remove port from registry URL in Gitlab UI

Tags: gitlab

We’re running Gitlab with docker-compose and have the registry enabled. On our server where the docker container’s running we’re running a NGINX that proxy_pass https://our-registry.com to the port we have exposed the registry on. That works fine and all.

Our problem is that in the Gitlab UI it’s showing the registry URL as https://our-registry.com:5005.
Using the URL with that port will not work. How can we make the UI not show the port? We have already tried setting the registry_external_url to https://our-registry.com but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the relevant configurations you've made in your gitlab/NGINX configuration files? When you say "without success" -- can you elaborate on exactly what's not working? What error messages or behavior do you observe that's unexpected? The docs show how to configure this under [Configure Container Registry Under its Own Domain](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#configure-container-registry-under-its-own-domain) -- Have you tried following that?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the config below from gitlab.rb worked for me.

```
gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5005"
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks! I only set `registry_external_url` and `registry_host`